# Date conversion not working correctly

Tags: java, android, date, date-conversion

I have the following code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(SQL_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT);
Date startDate;

startDate = (Date) dateFormat.parse(some_string_represents_date_received_from_sql_server);
```

where SQL_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT is:

```
public static final String SQL_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
```

For some reason when 
some_string_represents_date_received_from_sql_server = `'2014-02-05T12:15:59.417'` I get this wrongly converted to `1388916959000` ticks which mean `Sun Jan 05 12:15:59 GMT+02:00 2014` .

and when I have
some_string_represents_date_received_from_sql_server = `'2014-01-30T16:30:00.437'` I get this correctly converted to `1391092200000` ticks which mean `Thu Jan 30 16:30:00 GMT+02:00 2014` .

Any ideas?

Comment: `public static final String SQL_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `DateFormat` for parsing as `public static final String SQL_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";` instead of `public static final String SQL_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";`

Comment: Man, I'm stuck on it for hours. Thank you both Trushit and Artoo.

Answer (score 5):

In your date format you're specifying minutes (**mm**) instead of months (**MM**).